# Encrypting/Decrypting connection string from C# code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Is there any way I can achieve this encrytption and decryption of connection string from my C# code.

like we do

aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings"

aspnet_regiis -pd "connectionStrings"

Thanks

Comment: Which C# code *where*? Ultimately, it comes down to ***what attack vector are you trying to protect***. You need to state clearly the attack vector to know whether encryption would actually add any security, vs just cause inconvenience. For example, the attack vector on aspnet_regiis is that it protects the files from inspection outside of your application, by somebody with a copy of the files. It doesn't protect the data from anything that has access to the running app itself.

Comment: The reason is if connection string have any password it not be shown in a clear text

Comment: @Christian K, how can I accept an answer which is not useful for me?

Comment: @BreakHead, you probably shouldn't. However - and I don't really bother to look through all your open questions - keep in mind sometimes the right answer is the one that shows that the question was not good/answerable to start with - may that be satisfying for the questioner or not.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]encrypt+web.config

Comment: How are you currently approaching your design and using the connection strings in your application?  Are they in the web.config or in the code behind?  Are they being dynamically determined based upon operating environment?  Do you have a single class setting the values?  Are you using a Dataset that has it hardcoded?  I could go on, but as @Marc-Gravell said, we need more information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
static public void ProtectSection()
{
    // Get the current configuration file.
    System.Configuration.Configuration config =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

    // Get the section.
    UrlsSection section = (UrlsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");

    // Protect (encrypt)the section.
    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");

    // Save the encrypted section.
    section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;

    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);

    // Display decrypted configuration 
    // section. Note, the system
    // uses the Rsa provider to decrypt
    // the section transparently.
    string sectionXml =
    section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();

    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted section:");
    Console.WriteLine(sectionXml);
}
```